# sql count query with case statement

Tags: sql, postgresql, case

I have to execute a query from three tables avg_salary, person and emails. This simple sql query works fine.

```
SELECT avg_salary.id, COUNT(emails.message_from) AS email_PGA
FROM avg_salary, person, emails
WHERE person.works_in = avg_salary.id    
AND person.email_address = emails.message_from
AND person.salary::numeric > avg_salary.avg
GROUP BY avg_salary.id
```

But I want to add another column `email_PLA` with the condition when
`person.salary::numeric < avg_salary.avg`. I can do that by joining the whole query again. But I want to use `CASE` in this situation. And even after trying so many times I can't get the syntax right.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I assume you need another count?
You would need something like:

```
SUM(CASE WHEN (person.salary::numeric < avg_salary.avg) THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS email_PGA
```

Comment: Thanks. I applied your suggestion as:
SELECT avg_salary.id,
SUM(CASE WHEN (person.salary::numeric > avg_salary.avg) THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS email_pga,
SUM(CASE WHEN (person.salary::numeric < avg_salary.avg) THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS email_pla
FROM email.avg_salary, email.person, email.emails
WHERE person.works_in = avg_salary.id
AND person.email_address = emails.message_from
GROUP BY avg_salary.id
and it worked.

Answer (score 1):

You can do *conditional* aggregation by using case `expression` and always use explicit `JOIN` syntax

```
SELECT avg_salary.id, 
       SUM(CASE WHEN p.salary::numeric > asal.avg THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS email_PGA,
       SUM(CASE WHEN p.salary::numeric < asal.avg THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS email_PLA
FROM avg_salary asal, 
INNER JOIN person  p on p.works_in = asal.id
INNER JOIN emails e on e.message_from = p.email_address  
--WHERE p.salary::numeric > asal.avg
GROUP BY avg_salary.id;
```

Answer (score 0):

If you need different columns on specific conditions you have to do different SQL queries.